# Almost Sure Convergence of a Sequence of Random Variables Which is a Function of Uniform Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $u\in[0,1]$ be a uniform random variable. Let define another random variable $X_n = \frac{n}{1+n^2 u}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that the sequence of random variables $X_n \to 0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$.

**My attempt:** Let us define a probability space $\Omega$. We know for any $\omega\in\Omega$, $u(\omega)$ is a finite number, say $k$, in the interval $[0,1]$. If we look at this $k$ as a deterministic number, it is obvious that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 k} = 0$.

**Question:** I am having a hard time justifying the case when $u(\omega)=0$ for some $\omega\in\Omega$. How can we make sure that such $\omega$ will not make the sequence $X_n$ go to $\infty$ because $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2 \times 0} = \infty$.

I appreciate any comment or response.

Comment: I think your attempt can be used for convergence in distribution and in probability but not almost surely.  Meanwhile $u(\omega)=0$ on a set of measure zero and it not worth worrying about.

Comment: You are basically done.  You showed $\{U>0\} \subseteq \{X_n\rightarrow 0\}$, so it immediately follows that $P[U>0] \leq P[X_n\rightarrow 0]$.  Note that it helps to use capital letters for random variables.  Your final question is unusual, it is like asking "how can we make sure $0=1$?" (Answer: We cannot because it is not.)

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your comment. I think what you said the convergence in probability, right? I wonder how can we show this for almost sure convergence. I appreciate any comment or hint.

Comment: @Henry, thanks. I agree $u(\omega)=0$ is a zero measure set. Is this enough for the almost sure convergence? Do we need to use a specific theorem from probability theory?

Comment: No, "almost sure" convergence is the same as "with probability 1" convergence, and that is exactly what you have proven, you are 99% done and you do not know it.  Did you read my prior comment?  You seem to have ignored the inequality $P[U>0]\leq P[X_n\rightarrow 0]$.  Perhaps you can calculate the left-hand-side of that inequality.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thanks @Michael !

Comment: Yes, recall that convergence to 0 almost surely means $P[X_n\rightarrow 0]=1$, and note that $$P[X_n\rightarrow 0] = P\left[\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega)=0\right]$$  Meanwhile convergence to 0 in probability means for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $P[|X_n-0|\geq \epsilon]\rightarrow 0$.